# jQuery Modal close callback

Tags: jquery-ui

How can I set a callback function to be ran when a modal dialog is closing, without the click of a button or close (x) icon?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can also try,

```
$( ".selector" ).dialog({
   beforeClose: function(event, ui) { ... }
});
```

This event is triggered when a dialog attempts to close. If the `beforeClose` event handler (callback function) returns false, the close will be prevented.

Answer (score 1):

Why dont you try the event [`close`](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/#event-close) of jQuery UI dialog?

Code examples

Supply a callback function to handle the close event as an init option.

```
$( ".selector" ).dialog({
   close: function(event, ui) { ... }
});
```

Bind to the close event by type: dialogclose.

```
$( ".selector" ).bind( "dialogclose", function(event, ui) {
  ...
});
```